# UIKit - Disable Slide Over and Split View programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, apple-silicon

I'm trying to port iOS Unity Game for the new Apple Silicon Mac. For supporting window resizing and fullscreen, I just set `UIRequiresFullScreen` to false, it works well on the Apple DTK.

But the slide-over and split automatically enabled with the plist property modified. The ARM Mac version runs on the iPad scheme, but we don't want the split and slide over feature enabled for iPad device. Can I disable the Split view feature programmatically when the device is determined not running on Mac?

It would be appreciated if anyone can give some ideas...

```objectivec
if (![NSProcessInfo processInfo].isiOSAppOnMac){
   // code to disable split view and slide over
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically, it is not possible for iPad. This is just plist value that can't be changed at runtime. You use case is valid You can raise a bug with apple, they might lok into it. they may introduce different plist for mac, or some other way around it. Right now at runtime this is not possible.